# What is the title of the book about vampires surviving at the end of Earth's existence?

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, vampire, apocalypse

Some years ago I've read an excerpt from a sci-fi book, I don't remember the name or the author, just the premise. I'd really like to find it now. What is the name/author of the book described below?

It's billions of years in the future, human race (apparently) has long time since left Earth and relocated somewhere. Sun is expanding and will eath Earth soon. The last colony of vampires is barely surviving underground, keeping a (relatively) small number of humans for a food source.

Most of the vamps have been around for billions of years themselves, they know their time is ending and many of them are quite depressed and tired of "living" anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be [*Eternity's End* by Dan Bivens?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055720240X)

The human race has disappeared from the Earth in Space-Time warping ships, and the vampires have been living on Earth for millennia. The Sun has started to expand bringing with it total annihilation. There appears to be one-hundred Humans, and only eight surviving Vampires.

[Found here, from Google Books:](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=BIUyAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=vampires%20surviving%20at%20the%20end%20of%20Earth%27s%20existence&source=bl&ots=h6qGaQVmaG&sig=R8HD3T2HFOl6m3WR8tYrM0vRVQE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCtP34k7DZAhUjIcAKHRzMDwkQ6AEIPDAC#v=onepage&q=vampires%20surviving%20at%20the%20end%20of%20Earth's%20existence&f=false)

> Vampires!
>
> That was what their kind, I now just knew, had been called for the many ages of Man. And those vampires, I continued to just know, had co-existed with our kind since the Stone Age, and were still in existence at the approaching End of Time for Earth's solar system. An End from which **the Human race, as a whole, had escaped vie Space-Time warping starships**.
>
> And I also somehow just knew, without asking my mate, the original Daliamu Zabawaheshja, that these eight surviving vampires, because they had been reborn, **countless millennia ago**, as Undead creatures of the night, were, therefore, unable to follow Man into the distant darkness of interstellar space.
>
> ...A sun that, in its final death throes, had **begun swelling to a point where, eventually, nothing and no one would or could ever escape certain obliteration**. Not we force-bred hundred. Not these eight eternal vampires.

Comment: Yup, that's the one! I didn't expect the answer so fast. Thank you!